# Ansible loop not execute if same value

Tags: ansible

can i know in an Ansible loop is there a way not to execute repeated statement . Below is my code

vars.yml

```
type_of_fruit:
  - "lemon"
  - "orange"
  - "orange"
  - "pineapple"
```

main.yml

```
- name: Type of frutis
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ type_of_fruit }}"
```

Expected

```
"lemon"
"orange"
"pineapple"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the items, e.q.

```yaml
    loop: "{{ type_of_fruit|unique }}"
```